# Is there a javaScript engine where I can run my code without being forced to use a browser?

Tags: javascript, ide, javascript-engine

Is there any way to write and run a JavaScript code without having a need to run a browser and use its JavaScript engine?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this code in a way would still 'interact' with HTML DOM or you just want JavaScript syntax on non web environment?

Comment: just JavaScript syntax; DOM is not needed.

Answer (score 5):

I am amazed no one has pointed this out yet.

***Windows includes a Javascript engine that can be used from the command line.***

All versions of Windows, since Windows 98, have included something called "[The Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)". It's a windows-standard way to support script "engines".  Since the first release, WSH supports JScript, Microsoft's version of Javascript. Among other things, this means that, from a windows command line, you can just invoke the name of any *.js file, and it will run in the JScript engine. (via either wscript.exe or cscript.exe)

> You can see this question:  [What is the ProgId or CLSID for IE9's Javascript engine (code-named "Chakra")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690/what-is-the-progid-or-clsid-for-ie9s-javascript-engine-code-named-chakra/7168837#7168837) to learn how to invoke the higher-performance IE9 Javascript engine from cscript.exe.

I use cscript.exe to run jslint from within emacs, on any .js module I'm editing.  (via flymake-for-js)  Lots of people use .js modules to do system maintenance or administration.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) JS Engine.

Answer (score 1):

There's node.js

http://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

On top of that, you can take a look at jslib http://code.google.com/p/jslibs/ which uses [spidermonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey), the core of javascript engine in firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Java 6 has support for executing JavaScript within Java code. You can load any arbitrary JS file and execute (eval) it.

Here's a simple code example for the same:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/ExecuteJavascriptscriptinafile.htm

Answer (score 0):

Might as well throw Google's [V8 engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) into the ring

Please see [JasonMP85's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941411/executing-javascript-without-a-browser) for a few more options as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of independent, js engines, adding to previous post

- JSDB, http://www.jsdb.org/
- Narwhaljs, http://narwhaljs.org/

There are tons of standalone JS engines and framework built on top of them (Node.js, ringojs, etc.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_server-side_JavaScript_solutions

Well, all you need is to choose based on what you need.