# JavaScript standalone IDE without browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ide

So I have been looking for an IDE that allows me to run JavaScript just like Eclipse/VS would allow me to write Java/C#. I want to write some code and see the output on the console (possibly within the IDE itself), without having to open the browser. I know you can run JS programs from command line using `node file.js`. But I'm trying to avoid having to do that every time. I want to press a run button and see the results on the console. Is there something already out there. Can I configure my IDE in certain way to achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of things would you want to do with it? Do you want a DOM to play with, file io, or AJAX?

Comment: for now, just as a playground for JavaScript codes. but i guess it could be useful for util based node packages development as well ... since JS can run w/o browser as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Atom https://atom.io/ for the editor with embedded console and excellent JavaScript support (actually it's a browser inside).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), it is open source and free.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Is there a javaScript engine where I can run my code without being forced to use a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223649/is-there-a-javascript-engine-where-i-can-run-my-code-without-being-forced-to-use)

A lot of alternatives of command-line and engines to try js without the need of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug browser js with any jetbrains IDE, however I find chrome to be much better for debugging browser code than the jetbrains plugin. You can easily debug node by editting your debug configurations in any jetbrains IDE. Just download the node plugin https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/running-and-debugging-node-js.html