# Render Latex in org-mode buffer using MathJax

Tags: emacs, latex, elisp, org-mode, mathjax

`org-preview-latex-fragment` lets us to render Latex fragments using either dvipng or imagemagick. But both of these are methods are painfully slow! Yet, Org-mode uses MathJax as its default processor for html exports. So I wonder, is it possible to use MathJax for previewing Latex inside the buffer, as well?

Thanks!

Comment: MathJax runs on JavaScript; typically inside a browser. So org-mode should add support for an external JS engine for rendering. Indirectly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941411/executing-javascript-without-a-browser

Comment: seems there is solution for this, looking forward to someone to add the feature to org-mode or write up a plugin for it. Latex is too big and really out dated. I wish i can do this, but lack the skills ...