# Call a JS function in C

Tags: javascript, c

i have to generate a PDF with a dynamic calendar, the main program must be written in C. Is there a way that i could call a JS function in my program to do it? Or "link" both. I'm using windows
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a JavaScript runtime you can embed in C? Would it be easier to fork a `node` process?

Comment: You could embed a JS engine in your program or execute a command that runs JS. Perhaps take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941411/executing-javascript-without-a-browser

Comment: But i don't understand how could i execute a command that runs JS in C... Is that possible? How? With an external library?

Comment: The easiest approach might be to write a complete JS program that takes input from a file and writes output to a file. Then, the C program sets up its input, calls the JS program with system(), then finishes with its output.

Comment: That would be a great ideia @LeeDanielCrocker , but i have to print a specific month from a specific year, the C program recieve the input with the month and year the user wants to print and calculate how many days the month has. Is there a way to "pass" a variable which contains the number of days to the JS program with the system()?

Comment: In a file, on the command line, over a socket, over a pipe...